# Can Windows Nano server run SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, windows-nano-server

I am investigating the possibility of running a Nano server for a web service.  I have been trying to find out if it can run an instance of SQL server 2016 in addition to IIS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about compatibility and support for an OS which is still being developed, and there are no official sources to support any possible answer.

Comment: It is not off-topic due to potentially having no definite answer.  Just because you or I have not found official sources does not mean they do not exist.  I am also open to speculation from those who have been using the OS and have experience with SQL Server requirements.  Your contribution is of course appreciated and I hope others might have insight to share as well.

Comment: We can only speculate; only Microsoft knows if, when and how SQL Server will be supported on Windows Nano Server... and they can change this at will while WS2016 development keeps going on. As such, it's completely useless to discuss this here and now.

Comment: You are entitled to believe speculation is useless(even though you supplied an answer based on speculation), but that does not change the first part of my previous comment.  Just because you or I have not found official sources does not mean they do not exist (although it does seem that way).

Comment: Now that Server 2016 has hit RTM, there should be a definitive answer.  I haven't found one, though.  However, the existence of [this uservoice suggestion](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/295068-nano-server/suggestions/7927659-make-mssql-available-for-nanoserver) implies that the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be surprised if the answer was a resounding "NO!", since SQL Server requires lots of features to be enabled in the underlying operating system (even installing it on a Server Core edition can be quite painful).

But since there isn't actually *any* information about this specific issue (and WS2016 is still being developed, including the Nano Server edition), the question is currently unanswerable. It will ultimately depend on whether Microsoft will support it or not.

Comment: Brent Ozar [says no](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/10/video-office-hours-20161005-transcriptions/).  He usually knows what he's talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Nano Server is not listed in Books Online as a supported Edition:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms143506.aspx